# Having issues with svg files from libre maps

Tags: vector, svg, mapping

For a while I thought there was something wrong with my code, but it looks like there is an issue with the svg files on libre maps.

I've been trying to use their svg files with jvectormaps but they wouldn't work no matter what.  Then I tried to use object and the img tag to just embed them, and they still won't work so obviously there's something wrong with these svg files.  I tried a few things such as removing the xml tag, and updating the doctype, but still no luck.

This is one of the files I'm having an issue with.
http://libremap.org/data/boundary/2000/sub_county/svg/cs42_d00.svg

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is a problem with their SVGs.  The root `<svg>` element should have an `xmlns` attribute, but it doesn't.

Eg. the map you linked to starts with:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax"
     viewBox="2.682664 439.717923 49.914144 29.355176">
```

it should be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax"
     viewBox="2.682664 439.717923 49.914144 29.355176">
```

Standalone SVGs must have the namespace attribute.  You should probably report it as a bug to them.

In the meantime, you can download the SVG and correct it yourself.  Then use your local copy.

**Update**

There is another issue with the SVG.  It has `fill` set to `none` and `stroke-width` set to `0` (see line 8).  So nothing will display by default.  If you change either of those (see line 8), it will display.

```
<g id="Unknown_Area_Type_cs42_d00_e00" style="fill:grey;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);
   stroke-width:0.01;stroke-linecap:round">
```

Perhaps it was intended that you use CSS to style the map.  Having something like the following should also work:

```
g#Unknown_Area_Type_cs42_d00_e00 *
{
   fill: grey;
   stroke:rgb(255,0,0);
   stroke-width:0.01;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a huge problem. Unfortunately that still didn't fix the issue.  In illustrator this large file just opens up blank and when converting to jvectormap js, it just shows grey.

There's definitely something else wrong with the map and libremap,org doesn't seem to have a contact us page.

I'm sure there's more wrong with the svg. It could just be in an older format.

Comment: I've updated the answer to deal with the other reason it is not displaying.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't work either.   I'm using a new map our graphic designer has given me and it works, kind of.

After I convert the file over to js
(http://svgto.jvectormap.com/) 

And upload it, I get this error.
Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="scale(NaN) translate(NaN, NaN)"

It can't calculate the scale numbers for whatever reason, and the map shows up but it's huge and won't fit in the container.

I can't give you a url but I can perhaps put the code in playpen or somewhere.

The widths inside the js file are "width":1700,"height":1100,.

Tried removing them...

Comment: Thank you, it's all working now. I would thumb up your comment but I don't have the rep.